# Order of execution in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

If I have the following query

```
SELECT (...) WHERE some_field IN (1,2,3) AND some_field NOT IN (1)
```

will the query only look upon when some_field is (2,3)?

Comment: Did you try to run it?

Comment: It should go like this > where `A` is `some_field` and `B` is `some_other_field` : `A` and `B` will BOTH be evaluated and you'll get an answer if BOTH are TRUE

Comment: In the time it takes to ask the question, you could answer it yourself.

Comment: @Fane . . . You are talking about a compile-time optimization.  MySql does have several of these.  However, this construct is rather unusual, so I'd be surprised if there is a specific optimization to combine the two clauses.

Comment: @Fane: Are you asking if the MySQL query optimizer will optimize this as `some_field IN (2,3)` or are you just simply asking if this query will get the rows you expect?  Furthermore, do you have an *actual* query that you are having trouble with?

Comment: This is a great place to start http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first operand is completely evaluated and all side effects are completed before continuing evaluation of the logical AND expression.

The second operand is evaluated only if the first operand evaluates to true (nonzero). This evaluation eliminates needless evaluation of the second operand when the logical AND expression is false.

Comment: Therefore it will return the whole (1,2,3)?

Comment: This is called "short-circuit evaluation".

Comment: @Fane: No, it will return `(2,3)`.  All this means is that `some_field NOT IN (1)` will only be evaluated *if* `some_field IN (1,2,3)` actually finds anything.

Comment: I'm a bit zombie right now but my guess would be `(2,3)` it mostly depends on your `some_field`

Comment: @Fane let me try to elaborate.. let's say your operands are `A` and `B`. The way it is typed your `B` **will exclude** `A's 1` so what's left is `(2,3)`. It gets clearer if you draw some sets : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will filter the results based  given the first operand results a non empty set